# Facebook Connect for iPhone persistant login

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

I have implemented Facebook Connect in my iPhone project and it is working great. The only problem I have is that every time the user closes the app, the next time they load it they have to re-enter their username and password to login even if the 'keep me logged in' box is checked.

My question is is there a way to save the user's session so next time the app is launched they are automatically logged into Facebook Connect without any prompts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session information will be stored on the iPhone disk in your application's preferences, so you won't have to ask the user to log in every time they use your application. After you've created your session object, call [session resume] to resume a previous session. If the session has expired or you have yet to create a session, it will return NO and you will have to ask your user to log in. Sessions expire after two hours of inactivity.

Sorry forgot that Iphone used a totally different login system, i.e oAuth. Recheck